# Удалить значение по умолчанию NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день, у меня такая проблема, как удалить padding между nav header и первым элементом navigation view?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. 3й пункт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут все просто, вам надо переопределить в `dimens` вашего проекта, параметр `design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding`.

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое, я тоже переопределил этот параметр, но в нем также добавил tools:override="true", но не сработало))) удалил этот параметр tools и все отлично получилось